# wc_get_template for orders.php page not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been creating a modified My Accounts UI and am unable to get past order history to populate with the `wc_get_template` command for the `/myaccounts/orders.php` page. I have customized this page so its in the same directory as `my-account.php` hence why my `wc_get_template()` does not have /myaccounts/orders.php instead.

Here is my code:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );

wc_get_template( 'orders.php', array('user_id' => $user_id , 'has_orders' => true ),'', $path); ?>
```

I feel like I might be missing something in the array... but not sure what. I have set `has_orders` to `true` for testing purposes

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who was looking for an answer you must pass 2 more arguments in the `wc_get_template` for orders.php:

```
$current_page = empty( $current_page ) ? 1 : absint( $current_page );
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array( 'customer' => get_current_user_id(), 'page' => $current_page, 'paginate' => true ) ) );

wc_get_template(
'orders.php', array('current_page' => absint( $current_page ),'customer_orders' => $customer_orders,'has_orders' => 0 < $customer_orders->total, ),'', $path);
```